# How to sort a column while keeping the order of another column in R?

Tags: r, sorting

I would like to sort a column while keeping the order of another column in R. For instance, I have "year" and "region" variables in the dataset of "sales":

```
year region
2006     1 
2006   101 
2006   107 
2006    11 
2006    13 
2007     1 
2007   101 
2007   107 
2007    11 
2007    13
```

What I want is to have an ascending order for the "year" variable for each region while keeping the order of "region", which is neither ascending nor descending.

```
year  region
2006     1 
2007     1 
2006   101 
2007   101 
2006   107 
2007   107 
2006    11 
2007    11 
2006    13 
2007    13
```

I tried to use the `order` and `arrange` functions but they do not give me the result I want. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Read [`?order`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html). [`?sort`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sort.html). Look for the various `method=` options that are "stable", meaning that the order of ties is preserved (which is what you're asking for). Notably, `"quick"` *is not* stable, `"radix"` *is* stable, `"shell"` *may be* stable, and `"auto"` chooses based on some heuristics. The first doc says that `order` is always stable unless `method="quick"`, so you should be safe with `dat[order(dat$region),]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you can do:

```r
df[order(factor(df$region, levels = unique(df$region)), df$year),]
#>    year region
#> 1  2006      1
#> 6  2007      1
#> 2  2006    101
#> 7  2007    101
#> 3  2006    107
#> 8  2007    107
#> 4  2006     11
#> 9  2007     11
#> 5  2006     13
#> 10 2007     13
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(factor(region, as.character(unique(region))), year)
```

We fix the order of `region` by redefining it as a `factor`. The new `factor` region will be dropped as soon as the `arrange` operation is finished.

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
    year region
   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  2006      1
 2  2007      1
 3  2006    101
 4  2007    101
 5  2006    107
 6  2007    107
 7  2006     11
 8  2007     11
 9  2006     13
10  2007     13
```

`df` looks like this

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
    year region
   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  2006      1
 2  2006    101
 3  2006    107
 4  2006     11
 5  2006     13
 6  2007      1
 7  2007    101
 8  2007    107
 9  2007     11
10  2007     13
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `match` with `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    arrange(match(region, unique(region)), year)
```

-output

```
#    year region
#1  2006      1
#2  2007      1
#3  2006    101
#4  2007    101
#5  2006    107
#6  2007    107
#7  2006     11
#8  2007     11
#9  2006     13
#10 2007     13
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L), region = c(1L, 101L, 107L, 11L, 
13L, 1L, 101L, 107L, 11L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(year = c(2006,2007,2006,2007,2006,2007,2006,2007,2006,2007),
                  region=c(1,1,101,101,107,107,11,11,13,13)
                  )

dat %>% arrange(year)
```